# How to stop being redirected to other servers in CS 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I have been playing CS 1.6 in a particular server for a long time. The problem started just from today evening. Suddenly I observed everytime I connect to that particular servers address, I am redirected to some random server where the redirected server may be full or empty. The server is enlisted in Gametracker (ip: 84.200.5.189:27015). I can also see people are playing there, but sadly I cant join now. Please help me to fix this problem. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the game. No luck.

**EDIT**- The console after connection looks like:

> ]connect 84.200.5.189:27015
>   NET Ports: server 27015, client 27005
>   Server IP address 116.203.182.90:27015
>   Connecting to 84.200.5.189:27015...
>   Connection accepted by 84.200.5.189:27015
>   Unable to open resource/gamemenu.res
>   [AMXX] Simple Redirection - Redirecting to 46.17.98.104:27019
>   * Privileges set
>
> ### Connecting to 46.17.98.104:27019...
>
> You are using HLServer 1.16 by [RTsK] RATWAYER
>   Technical support - ICQ 289012
>
> ### Have Fun =)
>
> Redirecting connection to 93.119.24.96:27015;bind "h" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "v" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "x" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "z" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "c" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "ALT" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F3" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F4" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F5" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F6" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind bind "F6" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F7" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F8" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F9" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F10" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F11" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "F12" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "INS" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "DEL" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "PGDN" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "PGUP" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "HOME" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015";bind "END" "Connect 93.119.24.96:27015".
>   Connecting to 93.119.24.96:27015...
>   Connection accepted by 93.119.24.96:27015
>   Can't unbind ESCAPE key
>   * Privileges set

My config file is totally clean and it is "read-only". So how can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is the server full? Sometimes a group of servers are setup such that when you cannot join the primary server you are redirected to a secondary server. If there are only two open slots those slots are probably there so people join the server and get redirected instead of getting the "server full" message.

Comment: May be a messed up config file: delete your `config.cfg` file. http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1865696

Comment: @SadlyNot, That is not the case. I can chat in facebook with my co players there and they confirm me server is not full, rather less than half players are playing that time.

Comment: @Mistu4u If that's the case I can't say from experience what's happening :( best of luck figuring it out.

Comment: This happened with me too. Turns out server changes these bindings when we connect to it. It's best to setup your configuration and make it read only - [CS 1.6 redirection to other server issue](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2017/03/cs-16-redirection-to-other-server-issue.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I, along with other co players of the same server,  thought that we were being slow-hacked by the server. But later the admin himself informed us in Facebook that even he was facing the same problem. I don't know some kind of upgradation was then carried out in the server side and later everything returned to normalcy again. So it was not a problem in the client side, rather a server side problem and clients could do nothing about it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when some rogue server edits your config.cfg file and adds command to auto-redirect.

To stop this:

- Delete your config.cfg located in your /cstrike folder:

  - Location for STEAM: C:/ProgramFiles/Steam/Steamapps/common/HalfLife/cstrike/
  - Location for Non STEAM: C:/ProgramFiles/Valve/Counter-strike/cstrike/
- Start your CS and your new config.cfg will be auto written or type "writecfg" in console to make that file..

To avoid this in future --> in /cstrike folder make config.cfg as read only:

- (Right click the file -> Properties -> Tick 'Read Only')

and enjoy gaming... :)

Comment: For mac steam path is `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Half-Life/cstrike`.